# Reading a site into a dataframe, after logging in via Requests

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to create a data frame from a html page that has my weekly football picks.

I have bypassed the login via "requests" and the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

with requests.session() as c:
    url ='https://auth.cbssports.com/login?master_product=150&xurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbssports.com%2F'
    c.get(url)
    login_data ={'dummy::login_form':'1', 'form::login_form':   'login_form', 'xurl':'http://funkybunk.football.cbssports.com/office-pool/standings/live', 'master_product':'XXXX', 'vendor': 'cbssports', 'userid':'XXXX@gmail.com', 'password': 'XXXX', '_submit': 'Sign+In'}
    c.post(url, data = login_data, headers ={'Referer':'https://auth.cbssports.com/login?master_product=150&xurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbssports.com%2F'})

page =c.get("http://funkybunk.football.cbssports.com/office-pool/standings/live/1")
```

However, I don't know how to get the info from "page" into a dataframe.
When I use "pd.read_html" it still reads the login page instead of the page in the parameter of pd.read_html.

```
week1 = pd.read_html("http://funkybunk.football.cbssports.com/office-    pool/standings/live/1")
print(week1)
# trying to read it into a data frame; however it prints out the login page not the page I accessed via "page"
```

If I try:

```
  week1 =pd.read_html(page)
 #get an error saying I can't get response objects
```

If I run

```
print(page.content) 
# I'm able to see all of my info
#such as my team picks etc 
  """ I"m able to see all this info and more: id":XXX"41","snsScore":0,"numGames":16,"picks":{"NFL_MIA@SEA":{"winner":"SEA"},"time":"1473309152","NFL_BUF@BAL":{"winner":"BAL"},"NFL_OAK@NO":{"winner":"OAK"},"NFL_NYG@DAL":{"winner":"NYG"},"NFL_SD@KC":{"winner":"SD"},"NFL_GB@JAC":{"winner":"GB"},"NFL_MIN@TEN":{"winner":"MIN"},"NFL_CAR@DEN":{"winner":"CAR"},"mnf":"43","NFL_NE@ARI":{"winner":"ARI"},"NFL_DET@IND":{"winner":"IND"},"NFL_CHI@HOU":{"winner":"HOU"},"NFL_TB@ATL":{"winner":"TB"},"NFL_LAR@SF":{"winner":"LAR"},"NFL_CLE@PHI":{"winner":"PHI"},"NFL_PIT@WAS":{"winner":"PIT"},"NFL_CIN@NYJ":{"winner":"CIN"}}}"""

#However when I run try to read it via a dataframe
 #week1 = pd.read_html(page.contents)

#I only see:

#>>> week1
#[    0                    1   2
#0 NaN                  NaN NaN
#1 NaN  Live Scoring Notice NaN
#2 NaN                  NaN NaN
#3 NaN                  NaN NaN]
```

So all the data isn't being read into the dataframe for some reason.

I don't know anything about html coding and was able to use 'request' by watching a video and some trial and error.

I've been at it a couple of days but I'm stumped.

Thanks.

I'm using python 2.7 and Windows 7.

Thanks.

Comment: Python and Firefox don't share information. It's like "I couldn't get my husband's money from the ATM even though he knows his PIN" - won't work unless *you* know it ;) . You need to authenticate *in Python* (as in, the cookie you receive from the login needs to be available to your code). Try [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), these libraries make multi-request interaction with web servers easy.

Comment: Thanks. Request seems simpler to use. Do I have to worry about any security using when using requests?

Comment: Not really - the security is typically the concern of the server. Don't do anything you wouldn't do on a browser, and you're fine (e.g. posting your credit card information over non-SSL connection).

Comment: By the way, `requests` may *seem* easier because of that `auth=('user', 'pass')` example they have right when you land to their page - but you likely won't be able to use that. `auth` is for HTTP  Authentication (the ugly browser-based popup login); if you'd normally be typing your username and password into the webpage itself, then you would need to interact with the page - which means learning a bit more in-depth about whichever library you pick. There's also SO answers that are similar; but since the code needs to be customized to the webpage, you won't find any ready-made solutions.

Comment: Yeah. I just saw a video tutorial on it. It's a little more complicated than I expected. I'm going to try messing around with it and see how far I get. 
Thanks for everything.

Comment: I edited my original question as I got a little further but I'm not sure if it will go back to the top of the page so people will be able to see it.

Comment: Read the file with requests, give `pandas.read_html` the downloaded string, not the URL.

Comment: Hi, do you mean:

    week1 =pd.read_html(page)

I tried it, but I get an error that I can't read an response object.

Thanks.

Comment: Pass the actual source/content using the session object i.e page.content, pandas knows nothing about the session cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried "page.content" using  read_html but it's only reading some of the data into the dataframe.

I'm updated my question.